# select element in parent of parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile accordion menu set up like:

```
<div class="subCat" data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Subcategory Name</h3>
    <div class="itemImg">
        <img alt="Item 1" src="[image location]" /><span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="itemImg">
        <img alt="Item 1" src="[image location]" /><span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
</div><!--End of subCat-->
```

Which goes on for several subcategories. I have a bit of code to get "Subcategory Name" when the image is clicked:

```
var currCat=$(this).closest('.subCat').children('h3').innerHTML;
```

"this" is the imaged that's clicked, and I need to get "Subcategory Name" into currCat. However, currently I'm just getting "undefined" for the innerHTML and "[object OBJECT]" when I select children('h3'). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @thecodeparadox -- _"this" is the imaged that's clicked_, as the OP explained...

Comment: Funny that nobody posted this, but when you make a jQuery selection, each DOM element found is stored as an index in an array. So if you are looking for a single element you can add `[0]` to the end of the selection to only select the first DOM element (not jQuery object, but actual DOM element). You code will work if you make that simple change: `var currCat=$(this).closest('.subCat').children('h3')[0].innerHTML;`

Comment: Here is an example of using `.innerHTML` with a jQuery selection: http://jsfiddle.net/etk9w/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .text():

```
var currCat=$(this).closest('.subCat').children('h3').text();
```

You could use .html() too, either would work.

Comment: `.text()` will convert symbols like `<` into HTML entities like `&lt;`. `.html()` will not.

Comment: @Jasper That's incorrect... .text() ignores html and only returns text within html nodes.

Comment: @Kroehre http://jsfiddle.net/etk9w/. There's a demo showing what I mean. If you pass HTMl into the `.text()` function it will not ignore the HTML but make it readable in plain-text.

Comment: @Jasper That's not really relevant, the usage in the answer is .text() without any arguments, which returns only the text, and ignores the html nodes: http://jsfiddle.net/X3epk/ passing a string into .text() sets the text, the op is asking about reading the text.

Comment: I pretty much just wanted your answer to explain itself rather than stating "do this, it'll work." Your comments are great.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('img').click(function(e) {
    var currCat = $(this).closest('.subCat').children('h3').text();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvyjH/

Answer (score 0):

```
var currCat=$(this).closest('.subCat').children('h3').html();
```

Comment: Why use this? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

did you try `var currCat=$(this).closest('.subCat').children('h3').html();`

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
$('.subCat > h3').text();
```

or

```
var currCat=$(this).closest('.subCat > h3').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind with jQuery Mobile is that they do a fair amount of reconstruction with the HTML after it's been delivered to the browser. The accordion, for example, inserts several layers of `span` tags within the `h3`. I would install FireBug and use that to view the HTML after jQuery Mobile has reconstructed it. Also, as the other posts have mentioned, innerHTML is actually a property for native JavaScript, whereas jQuery uses `.html()` and `.text()`.